# ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE = 1 on armV7-a GCC 4.8.3

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, armv7

I am trying to cross-compile a multithreaded C++ application for a Cortex A8 (armv7-a) architecture.

I am using GCC v4.8.3.

The original code makes heavy use of futures. The compiler flags looks as follows:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -g -Wall -std=c++11   -c -o
```

When compiling, I get many errors similar to the following:

```
undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()'
```

I suspect this is because bits/exception_ptr.h isn't being included, because ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE is being evaluated to 1.

From exception.h:

```
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) && (ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE > 1)
#include <bits/exception_ptr.h>
#include <bits/nested_exception.h>
#endif
```

My research suggests that ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE should be 2 for architectures newer than armv5. Can anyone suggest what is happening here?

Regards,
Jakob

Comment: Have you tried `static_assert((__cplusplus >= 201103L) && (ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE > 1), "EXPLODE");` to validate your research?

Comment: You are right, my issue is not what I though it was. Your assertion does not fail. Furthermore adding #warning inside the conditional include above does show that the file is being included.

Comment: I guess this is not compiler error. This looks like linker error. Do you have STL compiler for your target platform?